# How to parse URI gracefully using Go?

Tags: go, parsing, url, uri

Here is my kafka connection information in etcd :

```
kafka://user:passwd@10.10.172.222:9092?mechanism=PLAIN&protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT
```

When i get the information string from the etcd, i want to get the username `user`,password `passwd` and host `10.10.172.222:9092`.

Now how can i parse Kafka connection information gracefully using Golang?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `net/url` library

```golang
kafkaUrl := "kafka://user@10.10.172.222:9092?mechanism=PLAIN&protocol=SASL_PLAINTEXT"

u, err := url.Parse(kafkaUrl)
if err != nil {
    // handle error
}
user := u.User.Username()
pass, isPassSet := u.User.Password()
host := u.Host // host or host:port
```

hostname and port separetely

```golang
hostname := u.Hostname()
port := u.Port()
```

Comment: Done! Thanks! (by the way, u.Host can get the host or host:port

Comment: Actually both it is just string so if port is provided it will be there if not... this is from source code see comment `Host string // host or host:port`

Comment: If you want to get hostname and port separatelly use `u.Hostname()` and `u.Port()`